# Allow leading and trailing blanks for each email address in comma delimited lis

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using the following regular expression to validate a comma delimited list of email addresses. It works great as long as the input is such that each email address does not have leading and trailing blanks. I would like to accept leading and trailing blanks for each email address within this list. How can I do this?

```
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailAddressesListValidator"  Display="Dynamic"
     ControlToValidate="stringTextBox" runat="server"  ForeColor="Red" 
     ErrorMessage="Invalid List. Please input a comma separated list of email addresses."
     ValidationExpression="^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*$"> 
   </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by changing the regular expression to the one below.

    ValidationExpression="^(\s*(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*\s*)*$"

Comment: The regular expression is same as original, except for \s* at start and end of each email address in the pattern.

Comment: Can someone please confirm if the above regex is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by changing the regular expression to the one below.

```
ValidationExpression="^(\s*(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*\s*)*$"
```